# $W$ is a $T$ invariant subspace of $V$ , and we know that $\sum^{k}_{i=1}a_i \in W$. show that $\forall i, a_i \in W ( 1\leq i\leq k)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I tried to prove this with no success:

$T$ is is linear transformation from $V$ to $V$ above $\mathbb F$. $a_1,a_2....a_k$ are eigenvectors for different  eigenvalues $\lambda_1,....\lambda_k$.
$W$ is a $T$ invariant subspace of $V$ , and we know that $\sum^{k}_{i=1}a_i \in W$. show that $\forall i,\, a_i \in W ( 1\leq i\leq k)$

**I tried to show by induction in the following way:**

**induction assumption**: $\sum^{k-1}_{i=1}a_i \in W$ , so that means $\forall i,\, a_i \in W ( 
1\leq i\leq k-1)$.

now we will show that if $\sum^{k}_{i=1}a_i \in W$ so $\forall i, a_i \in W ( 1\leq i\leq k)$
I got to the point where I show that $(\lambda_1-\lambda_k)a_1+....(\lambda_{k-1}-\lambda_k)a_{k-1}\in W$ but I cant use my induction assumption.

what is the right way?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this may be false, unless there's some additional assumptions. Is $V$ finite-dimensional? What about $\Bbb{F}$? Is it any arbitrary field, or is it supposed to be $\Bbb{C}$ or $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: yes;C  or R. V is finite-dimensional

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine. The statement is obvious if $k=1$. Assume now that it holds for a certain $k$. You want to prove that if $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}a_i\in W$, then each $a_i$ belong to $W$. Consider$$\lambda_{k+1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}a_i\right)-T\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}a_i\right).\tag1$$It belongs to $W$, of course. But $(1)$ is equal to$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(\lambda_{k+1}-\lambda_i)a_i=\sum_{i=1}^k(\lambda_{k+1}-\lambda_i)a_i.$$And now you can apply the induction hypothesis.

Comment: hi thank you but , how is this different from what I got to? I dont really see how it helps

Comment: Each vector $(\lambda_{k+1}-\lambda_i)a_i$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvector $\lambda_i$. So, you *can* use the induction hypothesis. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: the thing I dont really understand is - that my assumption is for a sum of vectors  a_i when they are all with the same Coefficient , but   (λk+1−λi)ai dont have the same one

Comment: No! Your assumption is that if a (finite) sum of eigenvectors of $T$ with distinct eigenvalues belongs to $W$, then each of these eigenvectors belong to $W$.